# How to denote network path in Win32_Directory.Name

Tags: vb.net, vb6, macros

My vb macro monitors the folder path for new file creation.I can able to monitor the paths in local drive.
How to provide the path for network drive???

here is my code below.here strDirToMonitor  is the place i need to give a network path (\share\files)

But the \ is not working ..

```
strComputer = "."
strDirToMonitor = "c:\\\\test"
'// Monitor Above every 10 secs...
strTime = "10"

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

Set colMonitoredEvents = objWMIService.ExecNotificationQuery _
("SELECT * FROM __InstanceOperationEvent WITHIN " & strTime & " WHERE " _
    & "Targetinstance ISA 'CIM_DirectoryContainsFile' and " _
        & "TargetInstance.GroupComponent= " _
            & "'Win32_Directory.Name=" & Chr(34) & strDirToMonitor & Chr(34) & "'")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A network path is specified  as follows: `\\COMPUTUER_NAME\SHARE\PATH`. Obviously, you'd need to escape  (double) the backslashes as you'd do with a local path

However, there are some differences in what you can do with network and local paths as remote ones aren't controlled by your local machine - so I'm not sure if what you're trying to accomplish will work.

Edit: As discussed in comments...

```
strComputer = "CompB"
strDirToMonitor = "c:\\\\test"
'// Monitor Above every 10 secs...
strTime = "10"

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

Set colMonitoredEvents = objWMIService.ExecNotificationQuery _
("SELECT * FROM __InstanceOperationEvent WITHIN " & strTime & " WHERE " _
    & "Targetinstance ISA 'CIM_DirectoryContainsFile' and " _
        & "TargetInstance.GroupComponent= " _
            & "'Win32_Directory.Name=" & Chr(34) & strDirToMonitor & Chr(34) & "'")
```

Comment: A local path will work with four slashes like ex: "c:\\\\test" but i dono how to use for network path . I tried \\\\\\\\share\\\\files but not working

Comment: see the example here http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/07/17/use-powershell-to-monitor-for-the-creation-of-new-files.aspx

Comment: Hmmm, sorry that didn't help. Having just re-read your code, it looks like you're actually connecting to the WMI service on the remote machine - have you tried just using the local path as if you were running on the remote machine?

Comment: Yes the local path works. but the problem is with network path.

Comment: No, you misunderstand me - You're connecting to the WMI of a remote machine in the line `GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")` - Which means that from that point onwards, the queries relate to that WMI not the machine the code is running on. Eg if you wanted to run the Code on `CompA` and Monitor a location `C:\Test` on `CompB`, `CompA` executes the script which contacts the WMI on `CompB`. When Querying the WMI, the paths should be relative to the WMI (eg local) so specifying `C:\Test` should refer to the path on `CompB` not `CompA`. In other words, Change `StrComputer`

Comment: To clarify, by specifying `.` as the computer, it's connecting to the local WMI. Changing `StrComputer` to `CompB` would cause the WMI instance in question to be `CompB`s not `CompA`s. then use a local path for `CompB` (All this assumes you're an Admin on CompB or have the appropriate permissions to do this)